# Codeigniter - sanitize function parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, sanitization

How can I sanitize a function parameter?
I have a url like: example.com/controller/function/parameter
and that parameter will be used to get data from a database.

There is a specific function or I need to use `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: You can check this page: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html I beleive what you are looking for is `$this->db->escape($your_variable)`

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple using native CI methods/functions:

```
$param = xss_clean($this->uri->segment(2));
```

Then pass the param to SQL query.

Comment: Since inside of the function that receives the parameter, the parameter is accessible just by its name, would it also be ok to just do `$param = xss_clean($param)` ?

Comment: Of course. Left side variable will then have sanitized value.